# how a javascript function variable data is passed to another page

Tags: javascript, raphael

i have a code here but i don't know how to pass it to the other page... basically it is inside a function so before the code there is a function but i think there is no need to worry about that what i need is to change the "alert" so some kind of variable where i can grab the value and output it, and also i would like to ask because the data in that function is an array is it correct if i write it like this? var x=new Array($(this).attr('fill')); and if it is correct how will i grab the array data into the other page?

```
$('text').each(function(){
alert($(this).attr('fill'));
```

i have a working link here but in this one i still need to change the alert into a variable i can call

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but to get data from one page to the next, you have the following options:

1. You can store the data on your server and each page can get the data from the server or have the server put the data into each page when the page is constructed.
2. You can write the data to HTML5 local storage in the browser and each page (on the same domain) can retrieve the data from HTML5 local storage.
3. You can write the data to a cookie in the browser and each page (on the same domain) can retrieve the data from the cookie.
4. You can pass data to the next page via the query string in the URL.

Javascript variables and properties of DOM objects live only for the duration of the current page.  When you go to another page, the entire javascript state is thrown away and does not survive on the next page (it is built again from scratch on the next page).  This is why you must store the data somewhere and then each page can retrieve the data.

Comment: oh i see so you mean it's not like how php passes the data to another page? sorry i am really confused i am just starting to learn javascript

Comment: 4) You can pass it along in the query string 5) you can use HTTP cookies

Comment: @LouieJayJayme - Client javascript is pretty much nothing like server-side PHP.

Comment: @vol7ron - I added the query string option.  Not sure how your cookie option is different than my #3.

Comment: well sadly i still don't have an idea how to do it :( i am using raphael js so i actually don't have much knowledge about it but do you guys know a simple way to pass an array variable into another page? i mean sorry if you answered this question already i am so confused :(

Comment: @LouieJayJayme - The options are spelled out in my answer.  If you don't know how to implement one of those specific options, you can Google to find code examples.  If you only need to pass the data to one other page, then I'd suggest you use the query string option and just launch the next page with the data in the URL as part of the query string.  You can Google "URL query string" to learn more.  If you want more specific help, you will have to be a lot more specific about exactly what you're trying to do.  An array of what?  How big is the array?  Are you launching next page immediately?

Comment: @jfriend00: What I meant as [`HttpOnly` cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie), which are still transferred through HTTP, but most browsers don't make them accessible via JavaScript or other tools.

Comment: @vol7ron - HttpOnly cookies cannot be accessed via javascript so you'd have to finish the story for how the data gets into the second page.  That didn't seem to meet the needs of the question.

Comment: @jfriend00: you are correct.  It's a safer alternative to your #3, but would require your #1 (or another method, which I'd rather not go into here)